# Do there exist smaller simplicial models of barycentric subdivisions?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, computational-geometry, simplicial-complexes, persistent-homology

Let $S$ be a simplicial complex and let $Bary(S)$ denote its barycentric subdivision.

Of course, the geometric realizations of $S$ and $Bary(S)$ are homeomorphic.

However, one issue that arises in practical computation utilizing barycentric subdivisions is the size of $Bary(S)$ is *much* larger than $S$, and so when $S$ is large, then $Bary(S)$ is HUGE!

Has there been any research on "smaller" (i.e., having less simplices) simplicial models of $Bary(S)$ for general $S$ that maintain isomorphic homology groups, i.e., are homotopy equivalent?

I believe this would have much relevance to many areas of persistent homology and computational geometry.

Comment: Isomorphic homology groups doesn’t mean homotopy equivalence. You need homotopy groups with all possible base points for this. Also, if you only demand homotopy equivalence you can take $S$ itself as a model. I guess you don’t want this so you need more conditions.

Comment: Subdivisions different from barycentric were studied in PL-topology.

Comment: True, I was rather sloppy with my language here. In general I am looking to preserve homology with a smaller subdivided complex than $Bary(S)$ (besides $S$ itself)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary finite simplicial complex $\ S.\ $ First, look at it purely combinatorially. Thus, let $\ \{a\ b\}\ $ be a 1-simplex of $\ S.\ $ Then define a subdivided simplicial complex $\ S(a\ b\ c),\ $ where $\ c\ $ is a new fixed vertex that didn't belong to $\ S.\ $ The simplexes that don't contain $\ \{a\ b\}\ $ stay the same. Every simplex
$$ \{a\ b\}\cup A $$
of $\ S\ $ that does contain $\{a\ b\} $
gets replaced by $\ \{a\ c\}\cup A\ $ and
$\ \{c\ b\}\cup A.$

Now we can iterate this easy construction.

---

---

In turn, let's look at a geometric implementation $\ |S|,\ $ where we will have $\ c:=\frac{a+b}2.$

We may like to have iterations that have smaller and smaller mesh (mesh of a complex is the maximal length of 1-dimensional simplexes of that complex) so that mesh approaches zero.

We achieve this effect of mesh approaching zero by each time selecting 1-simplex $\ \{a\ b\}\ $ that has the maximal diamater among all present 1-simplexes (i.e. this diameter would be the current mesh). The mesh will approach zero slowly but it will.

Comment: Let me describe this construction in different words. Any choice to write the vertices $V$ of a simplex $\Delta(V)$ as a disjoint union yields a way, say $V_1\cup V_2$, we get a decomposition of $\Delta(V)=\Delta(V_1)\ast\Delta(V_2)$, where $\ast$ denotes the join. We then can apply the subdivision only to one of the sets and get the subdivision $Sd(\Delta(V_1))\ast \Delta(V_2)$. The construction here corresponds to the choice of $|V_1|=2$. Of course other choices are also possible and give a lot of similar subdivisions .

Comment: @HenrikRüping, thank you for your comment. Yes, geometrically, I thought about joints.

Comment: @HenrikRüping, a (very) similar construction when |V_1|>2 will not decrease mesh (defined as in my "Answer").

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. Does this construction contain the same topological information as the barycentric subdivision? Does it give polynomially-many simplices in the size of the vertex set of $S$?